# CSVモード時に任意の複数行を選択することは可能ですか？

Tags: emeditor

CSVモード時に行番号クリックで行選択ができますが、Excelのようなctrl+クリックで任意の行を複数選択することは出来ないのでしょうか？

ctrl+shift+クリック等、いくつか試行したりメニュー、設定項目を眺めてみましたがどうも上手くいきません、ご存知ありませんでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

セル選択モードでは、複数範囲の選択はできないようになっています。セル選択モードを解除すれば、<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> を押しながら行番号の部分をクリックすることで複数行の選択が可能です。セル選択モードを解除するには、[CSV/並べ替え] ツール バーの画面図の部分をクリックして押下されていない状態にしてください。

[image: EmEditor セル選択モード]